# How to block users based on network or device name

Tags: .htaccess, web, ip, block, robots.txt

I searched online to find a way to block users from my website with specific network name or device name, and unfortunately, I did not find anything. I found [this](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/security/block-unwanted-users-from-your-site-using-htaccess) but it does not explain how I can deny users with network or device name. I am not sure, may be it is not possible to do so. I would be thankful to have the experts opinion on this matter.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, at least not with any purely server-side method. You can only block based on information that is visible to the server at the time of the request. This is limited to whatever the user-agent chooses to include in the request headers, which generally includes the IP number, port, and user-agent string, but does not include the device name or network name.